# can't apply style to a button on it's click event

Tags: html, css, dom

I have created a button dynamically in HTML5 + Javascript. I  have assigned a click event to that button. When i clicked it, it's content & background color should change. Content is changing fine, but bgcolor is not changing.

my code is;

```
<style>
.selectBtn{ height:60px;width:80px;background-color:yellow; }
</style>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById('abc');
function dx(){
var Btn = document.createElement('button');
Btn.type = 'button';
Btn.className = 'selectBtn';
Btn.innerHTML = 'SUBMIT';
container.appendChild(Btn);
Btn.onclick = function()
{
this.innerHTML='voted';
this.style.backgroundColor:'blue';
}
dx();
</script>
<body><div id='abc'></div></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `colon`. Use this:-

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";
```

Comment: That will not work. The property is called `backgroundColor` in JavaScript. But that colon in their code needs to become an `=`.

Comment: Thanks Olical,it's working fine now. I used  this.style.backgroundColor = "#f47121";

Answer (score 0):

You will wan't to change some things

```
var container = document.getElementById('abc');
function dx(){
   var Btn = document.createElement('button');
   Btn.className = 'selectBtn';
   Btn.innerHTML = 'SUBMIT';
   container.appendChild(Btn);
   Btn.onclick = function() {
      this.innerHTML='voted';
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if `Btn.type = 'button';` is valid but it sure is pointless
and on the style you want to change `:` to `=` you only use `:` in objects

Also you might wan't to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: Connor,i have removed Btn.type = 'button' as it's unwanted line.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not resist to show how I would have done this, just for fun, and its educational purposes.

```
window.onload = function(){

    (function(){
        var doc = document; 
        var get = function(id){return doc.getElementById(id);};
        var inject = function(el,str){el.innerHTML = str;return el;};

        inject(get('content'),'<button type="button" id="btn-select">SUBMIT</button>');
        get('btn-select').onclick = function(){inject(this,'Voted!').className = 'voted';};
    })();

};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNfBe/